# How to get input text value when change

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, url

I am trying to get input text value when I change it by typing button + or - so I can send it by form, but when I click on search button I don't get anything in URL. I got this : `myWebsite.com/?#`

I need to get the final value every time I make a change using buttons + and

```js
// increment num (Voyageurs)
$(".voyageurs-content__item-right :disabled").before(
  '<button type="button" name="button_dec" class="dec button-inc-dec"><span>-</span></button>'
);
$(".voyageurs-content__item-right :disabled").after(
  '<button type="button" name="button_in" class="inc button-inc-dec"><span>+</span></button>'
);

$(".button-inc-dec").on("click", function() {
  var $button = $(this);
  var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();

  if ($button.text() == "+") {
    var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
    $(".button-inc-dec.dec").removeClass("nb-underZero");
    $(".button-inc-dec.dec").removeAttr("disabled");
    // console.log("btn", $button);
  }
  if (newVal > 0) {} else {
    // Don't allow decrementing below zero
    if (oldValue > 0) {
      var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
    }
    if (newVal == 0) {
      $button.addClass("nb-underZero");
      $button.attr("disabled", true);
      newVal = 0;
    }
  }

  $button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);
  var id = $button.attr("id");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "?id=" + id + "&newvalue=" + newVal,
    success: function() {
      $button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);
    },
  });
});
```

```css
.search-box .search-box__voyageurs {
  padding: 0 4rem 1.5rem 4rem;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.search-box .search-box__voyageurs .voyageurs-content {
  width: 43rem;
  min-width: 43rem;
}

.search-box .search-box__voyageurs .voyageurs-content .voyageurs-content__item {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.search-box {
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 1rem 2.5rem;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 4.5rem;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 1rem 3rem 1rem 1rem;
}

.search-box .radius-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10.6rem;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 3.2rem;
  padding: 3.5rem 3rem 3.5rem;
}

.search-box .search-box__label {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.search-box .search-box__flex-bulle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.search-box .search-box__voyageurs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 1rem 1.5rem 1rem;
  text-align: left;
}

vertical-align: bottom;

}
.search-box .search-box__voyageurs button {
  color: #576070;
}
.search-box .search-box__voyageurs .voyageurs-content .voyageurs-content__item {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
.search-box .search-box__voyageurs .voyageurs-content .voyageurs-content__item:not(:last-child) {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}
.search-box .search-box__voyageurs .voyageurs-content .voyageurs-content__item:not(:last-child):after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #E1E1E1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.1rem;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.search-box .search-box__voyageurs .voyageurs-content .voyageurs-content__item:not(:first-child) {
  padding-top: 2rem;
}
.search-box .search-box__voyageurs .voyageurs-content .voyageurs-content__item .voyageurs-content__item-left p {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}
.search-box .search-box__voyageurs .voyageurs-content .voyageurs-content__item .voyageurs-content__item-left span {
  color: #576070;
}
.search-box .search-box__voyageurs .voyageurs-content .voyageurs-content__item .voyageurs-content__item-right {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}
.search-box .search-box__voyageurs .voyageurs-content .voyageurs-content__item .voyageurs-content__item-right .button-inc-dec.dec.nb-underZero {
  border: 0.1rem solid #B8BCC3;
  color: #B8BCC3;
}
.search-box .search-box__voyageurs .voyageurs-content .voyageurs-content__item .voyageurs-content__item-right .button-inc-dec.inc,
.search-box .search-box__voyageurs .voyageurs-content .voyageurs-content__item .voyageurs-content__item-right .button-inc-dec.dec {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 3.1rem;
  height: 3.1rem;
  border: 0.1rem solid #576070;
  border-radius: 50rem;
  padding: 0;
}
.search-box .search-box__voyageurs .voyageurs-content .voyageurs-content__item .voyageurs-content__item-right input[type=text] {
  color: #576070;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: none;
  width: 3rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.search-box .search-box__btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.search-box .search-box__btn>button {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #F93C64;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 1.5rem 3rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="search" id="az-search-box" class="validate search-box" method="GET" action="#">
  <div class="search-box__voyageurs">
    <div class="voyageurs-content radius-box">
      <div class="voyageurs-content__item">
        <div class="voyageurs-content__item-left">
          <p>Adultes</p>
        </div>
        <div class="voyageurs-content__item-right">
          <input type="text" class="voyageurs-choix" disabled name="voyageur_adultes" id="voyageur-adultes" value="0">
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="voyageurs-content__item">
        <div class="voyageurs-content__item-left">
          <p>Enfants</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="voyageurs-content__item-right">
          <input type="text" class="voyageurs-choix" disabled name="voyageur_enfants" id="voyageur-enfants" value="0">
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="voyageurs-content__item">
        <div class="voyageurs-content__item-left">
          <p>Bébés</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="voyageurs-content__item-right">
          <input type="text" class="voyageurs-choix" disabled name="voyageur_bebes" id="voyageur-bebes" value="0">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="search-box__btn">
    <button type="submit" id="search-form-submit">Search
        </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I voted to close this question because the code sample is too long. Please [edit] your post to reduce your code to a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the value of both `id` and `newValue` variables are `undefined`.
Moreover, the `newValue` variable has been initiated in the if-block when button increment clicked. As a result, the `newValue` will be `undefined` if button decrement clicked.

I assume that you want to send the `id`'s value of `input` name (such as: voyageur_adultes, voyageur_enfants,...) as follow:

```
var id = $input.attr("name");
```

```js
// increment num (Voyageurs)
$(".voyageurs-content__item-right :disabled").before(
  '<button type="button" name="button_dec" class="dec button-inc-dec"><span>-</span></button>'
);
$(".voyageurs-content__item-right :disabled").after(
  '<button type="button" name="button_in" class="inc button-inc-dec"><span>+</span></button>'
);

$(".button-inc-dec").on("click", function(e) {
  var $button = $(e.currentTarget);
  var $input = $button.parent().find("input")
  var curVal = parseInt($input.val());

  if ($button.attr("name") === "button_dec") {
    $input.val(curVal === 0 ? 0 : --curVal);
  }
  if ($button.attr("name") === "button_in") {
    $input.val(++curVal);
  }

  var id = $input.attr("name");
  var newValue = $input.val();

  console.log(`?id= ${id} &newvalue= ${newValue}`);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: `?id= ${id} &newvalue= ${newValue}`,
    success: function() {},
  });
});
```

```css
.search-box .search-box__voyageurs {
  padding: 0 4rem 1.5rem 4rem;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.search-box .search-box__voyageurs .voyageurs-content {
  width: 43rem;
  min-width: 43rem;
}

.search-box .search-box__voyageurs .voyageurs-content .voyageurs-content__item {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.search-box {
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 1rem 2.5rem;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 4.5rem;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 1rem 3rem 1rem 1rem;
}

.search-box .radius-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10.6rem;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 3.2rem;
  padding: 3.5rem 3rem 3.5rem;
}

.search-box .search-box__label {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.search-box .search-box__flex-bulle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.search-box .search-box__voyageurs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 1rem 1.5rem 1rem;
  text-align: left;
}

vertical-align: bottom;

}
.search-box .search-box__voyageurs button {
  color: #576070;
}
.search-box .search-box__voyageurs .voyageurs-content .voyageurs-content__item {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
.search-box .search-box__voyageurs .voyageurs-content .voyageurs-content__item:not(:last-child) {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}
.search-box .search-box__voyageurs .voyageurs-content .voyageurs-content__item:not(:last-child):after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #E1E1E1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.1rem;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.search-box .search-box__voyageurs .voyageurs-content .voyageurs-content__item:not(:first-child) {
  padding-top: 2rem;
}
.search-box .search-box__voyageurs .voyageurs-content .voyageurs-content__item .voyageurs-content__item-left p {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}
.search-box .search-box__voyageurs .voyageurs-content .voyageurs-content__item .voyageurs-content__item-left span {
  color: #576070;
}
.search-box .search-box__voyageurs .voyageurs-content .voyageurs-content__item .voyageurs-content__item-right {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}
.search-box .search-box__voyageurs .voyageurs-content .voyageurs-content__item .voyageurs-content__item-right .button-inc-dec.dec.nb-underZero {
  border: 0.1rem solid #B8BCC3;
  color: #B8BCC3;
}
.search-box .search-box__voyageurs .voyageurs-content .voyageurs-content__item .voyageurs-content__item-right .button-inc-dec.inc,
.search-box .search-box__voyageurs .voyageurs-content .voyageurs-content__item .voyageurs-content__item-right .button-inc-dec.dec {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 3.1rem;
  height: 3.1rem;
  border: 0.1rem solid #576070;
  border-radius: 50rem;
  padding: 0;
}
.search-box .search-box__voyageurs .voyageurs-content .voyageurs-content__item .voyageurs-content__item-right input[type=text] {
  color: #576070;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: none;
  width: 3rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.search-box .search-box__btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.search-box .search-box__btn>button {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #F93C64;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 1.5rem 3rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="search" id="az-search-box" class="validate search-box" method="GET" action="#">
  <div class="search-box__voyageurs">
    <div class="voyageurs-content radius-box">
      <div class="voyageurs-content__item">
        <div class="voyageurs-content__item-left">
          <p>Adultes</p>
        </div>
        <div class="voyageurs-content__item-right">
          <input type="text" class="voyageurs-choix" disabled name="voyageur_adultes" id="voyageur-adultes" value="0">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="voyageurs-content__item">
        <div class="voyageurs-content__item-left">
          <p>Enfants</p>
        </div>

        <div class="voyageurs-content__item-right">
          <input type="text" class="voyageurs-choix" disabled name="voyageur_enfants" id="voyageur-enfants" value="0">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="voyageurs-content__item">
        <div class="voyageurs-content__item-left">
          <p>Bébés</p>
        </div>

        <div class="voyageurs-content__item-right">
          <input type="text" class="voyageurs-choix" disabled name="voyageur_bebes" id="voyageur-bebes" value="0">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="search-box__btn">
    <button type="submit" id="search-form-submit">Search
        </button>
  </div>
</form>
```